# iReport one group by field only return one result

Tags: mongodb, formatting, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to show all people's comment after the diagram.
For some reasons it only show the last people's comment.
And I find the reason might because the position where you put.
For example, if I will put the name fields in detail colunmn it will dupulicate but the format looks like this:

```
-----------------------------
 Name          Rating          
Wilshere J.      3.5
Wilshere J.
Comments: He is good. 
          Very nice person.

Alex             3.2
Alex J.
Comments: He is good.

Leah             3.2
Comments: She is nice.

----------------------------
```

What I want the report looks like this:

```
-----------------------------
 Name          Rating          
Wilshere         3.5

Alex             3.2

Leah             3.2

----------------------------
Wilshere J.
Comments: He is good. 
          Very nice person.

Alex J.
Comments: He is good.

Leah C. 
Comments: She is nice.
```

Is there any solution to this formating problem?
I get the database from MongoDB. I don't think is the query problem.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Report Groups feature and use the Group Expression equals to your breaking rule which I believe is your column NAME.

**For IReport 3.0.0:**

1) Click to Reports Group button

2) Add New Group

3) Add ID for the group , for instance GROUP_NAME

4) Add an Group expression which will be for instance $F{NAME}

5) Add the columns to the new report band created

**For Ireport 5.0.0**

1) Right click over report name on 'Report Inspector'

2) select Add Report Group

3) Add ID for the group , for instance GROUP_NAME

4) Add an Group expression which will be for instance $F{NAME}

5) Add the columns to the new report band created

Comment: All the Employee's name and ratings are now in a consistent table, but where should I put my comments associate the employee names in another table? I tried to add in detail band and another group header, none of them works properly, they always intersect with the rating table.